# Error with the if and else statement

Tags: android

I am getting 3 different errors: identifier expected, unexpected token, unknown class: 'score'. These error's are in line 57-69.

The point of this code is to check if a checklist is checked and, if so, add 1 to score. It than changes the output text to a different string depending on score.

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    // Connects The variable to an xml id


    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    //sets the variable to 0
    int score = 0;

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.concern:
                if(checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.faith:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.respect:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.education:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.community:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    // adds the variables together to form a score

    if(score == 0){
        output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
    } else if( score == 1){
        output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
    } else if( score == 2){
        output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
    } else if(score == 3){
        output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
    } else if(score == 4){
        output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
    } else if(score == 5){
        output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community");
    } else{
        output.setText("Unknown");
    }
    // changes the output text based on score value
}
```

^^ Code where the error is located^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 1/27/2016.
 */
public class Pop_sallian extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));

        Button checkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Pop_sallian.this, check_Button.class));
            }
        });
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton_sallian);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^ Code where the pop up screen is launched and where the check button is^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you a Sallian?"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you meet the following prerequisites, if you do you may be a Sallian"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
        android:id="@+id/concern"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have faith in the presence of God?"
        android:id="@+id/faith"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/concern"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have Respect for all people?"
        android:id="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faith"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you value education?"
        android:id="@+id/education"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you inclusive in your community?"
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_below="@+id/education"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:textColor="#1eff00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/check"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

^^XML code^^

Comment: Why don't use a switch statement in place of the several if statements?

Comment: Would that fix the error?

Comment: See my answer below. It was a misplaced curly bracket.

Comment: If you want someone to help you, I would personally be more inclined to if you had a git url I could use to pull this code down and take a look.

Comment: And what will likely happen while you're pulling the effected piece out is that you'll isolate the issue and probably solve it yourself, win-win

Comment: Here's a link to the code file https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B26oY0FbX0IrQW9EN2NpcG9YXzg&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the closing curly bracket `}` in the wrong place. The function was ending before the `if`.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.concern:
                if(checked) {
                    score += 1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.faith:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.respect:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.education:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
            case R.id.community:
                if(checked){
                    score+=1;
                }
                break;
        }
        // adds the variables together to form a score

        //} <-- REMOVE THIS CURLY BRACKET

        if(score == 0){
            output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
        } else if( score == 1){
            output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
        } else if( score == 2){
            output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
        } else if(score == 3){
            output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
        } else if(score == 4){
            output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
        } else if(score == 5){
            output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
 } // <-- MOVE THE CURLY BRACKET HERE
```

Comment: It works but there's a new error. When I use my phone to click on the checkbox the app stops with the error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onCheckboxClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'respect'